# Git branch maintenance

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I would like to know how to create git branches as below:
--> I have a master branch
--> I want to create branch1, make some changes and will push later.
--> on same master branch i want to create another branch, branch 2 for some other changes.

my problem is i want to use both branches parallelly. 
when i create branch2, it has changes done in branch1 [changes not pushed ] i donot want that. so at present i am using git stash and then creating new branch.

i just want to know without using git stash can i create new branch. we have similar behaviour in clearcase. i can create any number of views there but changes from 1 view are not propagated to another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the two branches to be independent then they need to created from the same branch at the same time otherwise they will have dependencies.

```
git checkout -b branch_one
git checkout master
git checkout -b branch_two

git checkout branch_one
#Do stuff on branch one
git commit ...

git checkout branch_two
#Do stuff on branch two
#etc.
```

Comment: Ah... Paul's way of doing it is a bit better and cleaner. Probably go for that.

Answer (score 2):

```
git checkout -b branch1 master
git checkout -b branch2 master
```

creates new branches from `master`, regardless of what is checked out currently.

Comment: git checkout -b test master
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting

Comment: So commit or stash your changes. @sailajakasanur, do you want your changes on master, branch1, branch2, some combination, or none?

Answer (score 0):

Use Git Flow for this!

http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Much easier to handle all branch maintainance